# Report complains about Unsupported Release but no modules listed

Tags: 7

On my report page, I get a warning about Unsupported Release of modules or themes.

[image]

but when I click the "available updates" link, the next page tells me that all my projects are up to date.

[image]

I've tried clearing my cache and running cron but I get the same result.

EDIT:

Apparently this is a known bug that I missed in my searches. Unfortunately, the link to the bug below doesn't include any info on how to find out WHICH modules are unsupported. :( So, I have no way to figure out which things I need to upgrade or remove.

Where can I find a list of the unsupported modules in my installation?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to flag this, but questions related to known bugs are discouraged. Here's the thread: [Issue #961060: If a module is Not Supported, Drupal's warning links to available updates page, which says everything is OK](https://www.drupal.org/node/961060#comment-3754804)

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize this was a known bug, that page didn't come up in my search results. Thanks! Any idea how to find out WHICH project is the one that is unsupported? I have no way of finding out which thing I need to upgrade.

Comment: If you'd known you wouldn't have posted, right? :) I should have phrased that to say that it'll likely be closed for that reason. To find out which project, you can try `drush pm-updatestatus`? (Granted, it may be subject to the same bug.)

Comment: That worked actually! It gave me a list of the individual modules with their status and so I was able to determine which was unsupported! Woo! If you could please post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: That's excellent! Answer posted.

Comment: (Darn, missed my edit window.) I'm wondering if it would be helpful to share which module was the culprit, since according to that thread the problem you report seems to be caused when a module is "improperly unsupported" (whatever that means!). Anyhoo, I'll leave that up to you. Cheers -

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If using [Drush](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush), try:

`drush pm-updatestatus`

**Note**: It gives you a list of the individual modules with their status, so you can determine which one is unsupported!

Comment: Please check the note I added to your interesting answer, which is basically the comment from Kenny I (partially) integrated. If you don't like it: feel free to rollback, ok?